# How do you place a variable in a variable in php?

Tags: php, variables, dynamic

The code I have currently is:

```
${'wddx_'.$i}
```

Is there a way I can make it so that the $i variable is in the middle a bit like:

```
${'wddx'.$i.'_0'}
```

What is it that I have to do to get this to work?

I also need to have the variable in the middle.

Comment: `${'wddx'.$i.'_0'}` that works, but why dont you use arrays?

Comment: that should already be working... what error message are you getting, and can you show more of your code so we can see how you are using it.

Comment: I am extracting from an pre-built array where the naming for each part is a number. First I am "extract ($user_favs, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "wddx");" and then "for ($i=0; $i<=500; $i++){extract(${'wddx_'.$i}, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "wddx".$i);}" and after this is the bit i am trying to do which is "switch_to_blog($wddx0_0);" inside a "for" statement, there is other script as well inside the "for" which will also use this variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now fixed what I was trying to do, I just needed to us:

```
${'wddx' . $z .'_0'}
```

&

```
${'wddx' . $z .'_1'}
```

This has now fixed what I was trying to do. I used these variables inside this:

```
for ($z=0; $z<=500; $z++){

}
```

Thank you for your help anyway, it was very useful and I will remember about using arrays with better naming conventions when I do more coding in the near future.

Answer (score 3):

The code you should have

```
$wddx[$i]
```

and to make it in the middle

```
$wddx[$i][0]
```

please learn to use [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: I am extracting the variable from an array. Where the $i is an incrementing number. And then I need to add either "_0" or "_1" at the end to reference an array which is inside this array.

Comment: You have to have a *nested* array instead of these handmade indexes

Comment: I have trying to extract a prebuilt array in which there is another array both with the naming in a number format. I am then trying to the use to last part as a variable to dynamic load some content. (Using wordpress if this helps)